# Excel - Counting unique values with multiple criterias

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2011

I have a large scale data set and I am looking for a way to count the number of unique values:

```
Day -ID,    Location-ID,    Truck-ID

1,           18,              1

1,           19,              1

1,           18,              2

2,           18,              2

2,           18,              2

2,           18,              1

2,           20,              1

3,           21,              2

3,           21,              1
```

I want to find how many trucks are used to serve each location on each day?
For example, how many trucks are used to serve location#18 in day 2?

The answer is 2, because although there are 3 entries for location 18, day 2, there are only 2 unique IDs.

Comment: Is the answer 2 or 3? Although 4 entires for location#18, only 3 are for day #2. However, out of those 3, there are only 2 unique Truck IDs

Comment: for the example the answer is 2, but I need to find a way to calculated automatically in Excel

Comment: I think you should check out Pivot Tables. The problem is, I suspect that your example is just 1 of many queries you'll want to perform?

Answer (score 1):

This VBa does what you want

```
Public Sub Truckers()

'YOU NEED TO UPDATE THIS FIRST BIT

Dim entryOfLocation As String
entryOfLocation = "G1"

Dim entryOfDay As String
entryOfDay = "G2"

Dim result As String
result = "G3"

Range(result).Value = 0

Dim startingRow As Integer
startingRow = 2

Dim dayColumn As String
dayColumn = "A"

Dim locationColumn As String
locationColumn = "B"

Dim truckColumn As String
truckColumn = "C"

'STOP MAKING    ANY     UPDATES  :)

Dim uniqueIds As String

Do While (Range(dayColumn & startingRow).Value <> "")

    If Range(dayColumn & startingRow).Value = Range(entryOfDay).Value And Range(locationColumn & startingRow).Value = Range(entryOfLocation).Value Then

        Dim truckId As Integer
        truckId = Range(truckColumn & startingRow).Value

    Dim doesAlreadyExist As Boolean
    doesAlreadyExist = False

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim splitMe() As String
    splitMe = split(uniqueIds, ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(splitMe)

        If Not splitMe(i) = "" Then

            If Replace(splitMe(i), ",", "") = truckId Then
                doesAlreadyExist = True
                Exit For
            End If

        End If

    Next i

    If UBound(splitMe) = -1 Then
    uniqueIds = uniqueIds & truckId & ","

    End If


    If Not doesAlreadyExist Then
        Range(result).Value = Range(result).Value + 1
    End If


    End If

startingRow = startingRow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

[image]